# Streaming tweeter data into hdfs

Tags: hdfs, flume

ERROR node.Application: A fatal error occurred while running. Exception follows.

```
org.apache.commons.cli.MissingOptionException: Missing required option: f    
    at org.apache.commons.cli.Parser.checkRequiredOptions (Parser.java:299)
    at org.apache.commons.cli.Parser.parse (Parser.java:231)
    at org.apache.commons.cli.Parser.parse (Parser.java:85)
    at org.apache.flume.node.Application.main (Application.java:252)`ERROR node.Application: A fatal error occurred while running. Exception follows.

org.apache.commons.cli.MissingOptionException: Missing required option: f
at org.apache.commons.cli.Parser.checkRequiredOptions (Parser.java:299) at org.apache.commons.cli.Parser.parse (Parser.java:231) at org.apache.commons.cli.Parser.parse (Parser.java:85) at org.apache.flume.node.Application.main (Application.java:252)
```

The above error is what i get in the end after running this command:

./bin/flume-ng agent -n TwitterAgent -c conf -f /usr/lib/apache-flume-1.4.0-bin/conf/flume.conf

Can someone help me to fix thin issue so that i will be able to stream twitter data into hdfs please? `

Comment: Is the file path `/usr/lib/apache-flume-1.4.0-bin/conf/flume.conf` passed to `-f` correct?

Comment: Excuse me franklinsijo, but i do not understand what you mean by "passed to -f" can you explain it more please?

Comment: I am confused because when i trace the path i went to place-computer-system-usr/lib/apache-flume-1.4.0-bin (at this stage, bin and conf folder are at the same place) should conf folder be put into bin folder? flume.conf file is in conf folder. And when i open a terminal and execute this command: sudo gedit conf/flume.conf, i have this path: /usr/lib/apache-flume-1.4.0-bin/conf

Comment: Can you please tell me how to get the file path passed to -f please?

Comment: The error in question comes when the option `-f` is not provided or file does not exist. Try `ls /usr/lib/apache-flume-1.4.0-bin/conf/flume.conf` and see if the file exists?

Comment: This is what i get: [cloudera@quickstart ~]$ ls /usr/lib/apache-flume-1.4.0-bin/conf/flume.conf
/usr/lib/apache-flume-1.4.0-bin/conf/flume.conf
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$

Comment: This shows that the file exist right?

Comment: Do you please have an idea how to solve this? 2017-02-13 16:08:37,563 (Twitter Stream consumer-1[Establishing connection]) [INFO - twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger.info(SLF4JLogger.java:83)] 404:The URI requested is invalid or the resource requested, such as a user, does not exist.
Unknown URL. See Twitter Streaming API documentation at http://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api

Comment: The access tokens that you are using for twitter, are they generated with a valid twitter account or are they the same as in the tutorial?

Comment: They are generated with my twitter account. Should i regenerate and see weather it will help?

Comment: I just did it but not working still the same error. I found this online but i dont understand, because it is the same flume-source i have thanks alot i have also got solution...! Actually the v1 endpoints of the streaming
API have been expired from now on you have to use the new endpoints. We
have made modifications in the jar file you can download the jar file
from this link.... https://www.dropbox.com/s/qvudqfym5givwdg/flume-sources-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar?dl=0

Comment: I also tried this proposed solution: Put:
streamBaseURL=https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/
in
twitter4j.properties
file in your class path                                                                                                           But still not working

Comment: did you try running the agent after replacing the snapshot jar with the one available in the dropbox link?

Comment: I think it is the same flume-sources-1.0-SNAPSHOT right? if not, waht is the command to delete the old one and replace with the new one please?

Comment: The filename could be same, but the new jar could have made changes for the endpoints. Use this command `rm /usr/lib/apache-flume-1.4.0-bin/lib/flume-s‌​ources-1.0-SNAPSHOT.‌​jar` to remove the existing jar, after removing it copy the new jar in its place.

Comment: I am trying but not working: cannot remove `/usr/lib/apache-flume-1.4.0-bin/lib/flume-s‌​ources-1.0-SNAP‌​SHOT.‌​jar': No such file or directory

Comment: I think i have to delete all what i did before and start from scratch. Is there any command to delete all folder and files please?

Comment: If you are using `apache-flume-1.7.0-bin`, the command would `rm /usr/lib/apache-flume-1.4.0-bin/lib/flume-s‌​ources-1.0-SNAP‌​SHOT.‌​jar`. But in the previous comments you have mentioned the conf file in `/usr/lib/apache-flume-1.4.0-bin/conf/flume.conf`, verify whether your directories are correct.

Comment: Is there any command to check it? because i checked it manually and i can see that the path is the same as in the command. But the file has a locker on top of it. What does that mean?